# Does anyone know why an asset would appear invisible when imported into a scene in Maya?

Tags: maya

I'm getting this weird issue where when I import a particular asset into a scene in Maya, the asset does not appear to be visible in the scene. Everything else about it is normal (it has attributes, hierarchies, etc), but I can't see it. Does anyone know what might be going on?

If I import it into an empty scene, nothing goes wrong and the asset is normal

Edit: 
The answer was simple, we just hadn't imported the asset into the render layer.

Comment: As it turns out, we were using render layers and the asset wasn't being imported into the layer. When we do, it becomes visible

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming at all.